# Taking longer sample should not reduce the variance of the mean

Tags: variance, sample-size, model-evaluation, mean, random-walk

I have not realized completely why n times longer samples should give you n times shorter variance. However, I measure performance of my programs and there are some fluctuation due to PC state variation. In order to measure excution speed more precisely, the central limit theorem says that I should take longer run times. On the other hand, I notice that random fluctuation of PC state behave like random walk (PC slow downs at arbitrary moments or does not do that). So, two runtimes are differently affected by PC fluctuations and fluctuation size is proportional to sqrt(run time), if random walk formula is right. This cancels out the advantage or longer run. Is it right?